# Customize tooltip for multiple graphs in one plot

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, plotly.js

I am using [React plotly.js](https://github.com/plotly/react-plotly.js)
 in our application. We are plotting multiple graphs (line, area, bar). I need a way to customise look and feel of tooltip which appears on hover of graph.

This the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/km79ljmkmo) for references of my code.
This is the [output](https://km79ljmkmo.codesandbox.io) of the plot.

Currently the tooltips appear clumsy when we have multiple lines with multiple graphs which appear individually at each line.

Do we have a way to show only one tooltip with data of all lines at a hovered point.

[image]

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @GabrielDevillers updated the question with my code reference.